Installed poetry and updated path, but getting a command not found error
I'm getting the error zsh: command not found: poetry when I try to run poetry install.
I installed poetry via the manual installation instructions. I'm using oh-my-zsh
I've updated my path variable according to past answers. This is what I have in .zshrc:
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$HOME/.local/bin

It's usually easier to work with the linked path array than PATH in zsh, btw. path+=(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin $HOME/.local/bin) etc.

I don't know where you have installed it. Right before invoking poetry, do a echo $path. If the path looks good to you, execute poetry again, using the explicit abs path. If you still are stuck, post a screenshot of these tests.

@user1934428 Poetry was installed in the virtual environment I created for it (per the manual installation instructions linked above), so I guess that's why it wasn't working. There was nothing in $HOME/.local/bin. Deleted that environment and installed via pipx and everything works fine. Thanks.
Now I'm just confused about the installation instructions they have in their docs. They say you shouldn't activate the virtual environment where poetry is installed to use it.

I don't know poetry, but if you find the installation instructions confusing, I suggest that you create an issue there and ask that they make the instructions more clear in this respect. Your error message simply tells us, that there is no executable of this name in your PATH, and there is no alias of function of this name defined in the shell either. So you first have to find out, where your poetry is located, and then you can configure the shell, not the other way around.
